# spring HandlerExceptionResolver write json object to httpservletresponse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am handling negative cases like calling GET API which is actually a POST call. This gives Method Not Found Error with 405 status by Spring.

But I want my own exception so I added the following resolver:

```
 public class HandlerExceptionResolver 
 implements org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    Object handler,Exception exception) {
        logger.trace("-------------doResolveException-------------");
        System.out.println("-------------doResolveException-------------");

        if(exception instanceof HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) {
            Fault fault = new Fault();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            String errorMessage;
            try {
                errorMessage = mapper.writeValueAsString(fault);

                response.setStatus(405);
                response.setContentType("application/json");

                response.getWriter().println(errorMessage);
                response.getWriter().flush();
            }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        return null;
    }
```

But this doesn't writes the JSON to response.

Comment: Has `Fault` class fields initialized

Comment: yes they are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to want to write your own output using that response parameter.  Spring expects your method to return a ModelAndView instance, which you can populate with the data you want to send to the user (the model part) and the name of the view resource that will be used to render it.  You would then also need to define a new view resource that will just generate the JSON you want, out of the data in the ModelAndView...

Answer (score 0):

As for concern can you debug out the value of

> **errorMessage = mapper.writeValueAsString(fault);**

there is better way to do this exception handling.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HandlerExceptionResolver.class)
    public ModelAndView handleEmployeeNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
        logger.error("Requested URL="+request.getRequestURL());
        logger.error("Exception Raised="+ex);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("exception", ex);
        modelAndView.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());

        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

You can try also if you want to use **@ExceptionHandler** to handle this 
situation.